# How to get the client machine name using php / javascript

Tags: javascript, php, active-directory, ldap

I need to get the machine name and ip using php/javacript - when I run the webpage on the localhost I am getting the correct computer name and ip address but when I put the page on the webserver and run the same online - the code is returning the ip address of the client machine only NOT the name of machine-name.

I somehow need to get the client machine name and save it in the database for later operation.

So I tried in three ways:

Method 1 (php):

```
gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); -- return the ip


getenv('COMPUTERNAME'); -- return the ip only
```

Method 2(php):

```
echo shell_exec('echo  %computername%'); -- return none instead of client computer name
```

Method 3 (javascript):

```
alert(window.location.hostname);
```

None of them are not working.

I'm seeking your assistance.

Thank you.

Comment: `PHP` is server-side ...

Comment: Computer name I don't believe is sent to the server by default, it probably worked locally because the server and client were on the same machine. I'm also not sure there is a reliable way of getting it from the client via js, so the answer may be, you can't.

Comment: `PHP` would return the machine name where your code is hosted and not the machine agent accessing it. You have to reverse engineer the code.

Comment: so how can i do this?  This code return the ip address by automatically getting the computer name when i run on locahost. But not online. $ip = gethostbyname(getenv('COMPUTERNAME'));
echo '<br>'.getenv('COMPUTERNAME').' converted to '.$ip;

Comment: But there should be a way to get the computer name, is it ?

Comment: That will get the server's name (if set), not the client and may not return from the network interface you expect. Question is what do you _actually_ _need_ this for?

Comment: Could you please let me know how to reverse engineer the code?

Comment: Question is what do you actually need this for? I need to get the agent machine name only. I am getting the agent machine ip but that ip is not a fixed one so I want to get some fixed attribute from the agent machine so then I can automatically detect the machine and display some information accordingly.

Comment: As Jonnix and FirstIndex say you can't really get the computer's name through PHP or Javascript. Based on your comment the best bet is maybe use either a cookie or localstorage to set a unique identifier for that machine. Caveat is if the user clears storage or uses a different browser. However, having a user login of some kind helps offset that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment on the server is clearly different to your local machine.

Try var dumping the SERVER global to see what info you do have access to:

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

Comment: and then what ? how does this help OP figure out the client machine name ?

Comment: it helps to see what data they can get, and adjust their code/expectations accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I am using ip via                                                                                  
                                                                                                                     
$device_id = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);ME');